# Hibernate Validator : restrict validation to given constraints

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I want to perform the validation of my entities in two steps. While I use a defaultValidatorFactory to validate all the fields of my entities before persisting to the database, I would like to perform a partial validation of my entities at a earlier step. But I cannot find a way to configure my validator (or validatorFactory).

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Car {

    @NotNull
    private String manufacturer;

    @AssertTrue
    private boolean isRegistered;

    public Car(String manufacturer, boolean isRegistered) {
        super();
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.isRegistered = isRegistered;
    }
}
```

When I do the full validation of my entity, I use the given code:

```
Validator validator = validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> errors = validator.validate(car);
```

This works fine and validate both annotations NotNull and AssertTrue.

Now, I want to perform an partial validation. I mean by partial validation, I want to only validate, for example, NotNull constraints and ignore other annotations.

Is there a way to get a Validator or ValidatorFactory which uses a custom restricted list of validators?

You can find a lot of things to create your own constraint/constraint validator. In my case, I want to validate only some constraints.

Maybe I can create a custom ConstraintValidatorFactory and inject it in the Validation context? I found that we can reconfigure the context of the factory with the following code, but I don't know how to deal with it.

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validatorFactory.usingContext().constraintValidatorFactory(myCustomFactory);
```

For the moment, I'm lost. Someone has already done something like that? Do you have any idea how I can do this? Thanks for your time.

I'm using Java 8 and Hibernate Validator 6.0.14.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#chapter-groups

Comment: @Slaw In fact, I was looking for an alternative to groups. I have tons of entity to check (around 50+ classes) and 3 constraints I want to prevalidate. I was hoping I could use a custom validator in place of changing all entity constaints.

Answer (score 0):

As Slaw write - use groups.

**An Example**

```
package jpatest.jpatest;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class TestApp {

    /** A validation group marker */
    public interface ValidationGroup1 {};

    /** The bean  */
    public static class Bean {

        // Validate for group ValidationGroup1
        @NotNull(groups = ValidationGroup1.class)
        private String s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bean b = new Bean();
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        // Validation without the validation group => No ConstraintViolation
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Bean>> errors1 = validator.validate(b);
        assert errors1.isEmpty() : "No ConstraintViolation expected";
        // Validation with the validation group => 1 ConstraintViolation
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Bean>> errors2 = validator.validate(b, ValidationGroup1.class);
        assert errors2.size() == 1 : "1 ConstraintViolation expected";
    }

}
```