# Is there a way to configure the ConstraintValidator produced by ConstraintValidatorFactory?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I have two ConstraintValidator for the same entity:

ValidatorA

```
public class ValidatorA implements ConstraintValidator<ValidityAnnotationA, AnEntity> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final AnEntity entity, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // logic
        return valid;
    }
}
```

ValidatorB

```
public class ValidatorB implements ConstraintValidator<ValidityAnnotationB, AnEntity> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final AnEntity entity, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // logic
        return valid;
    }
}
```

In the unit test of ValidatorA, I want to validate my object only with ValidatorA (I do not want to deal with the side effects of ValidationB).

**How to get Validator where only ValidatorA is configured?**

The following code snip would use both ValidatorA and ValidatorB as well.

```
Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

Some hints/ideas from a similar question: [Hibernate Validator : restrict validation to given constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150511/hibernate-validator-restrict-validation-to-given-constraints)

Maybe I can create a custom ConstraintValidatorFactory and inject it in the Validation context? I found that we can reconfigure the context of the factory with the following code, but I don't know how to deal with it.

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
validatorFactory.usingContext().constraintValidatorFactory(myCustomFactory);
```

Note: Grouping constraints are not an option in my use case.

Comment: You can use Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator().validate(T object, Class<?> ...groups). Groups can be defined on your Entity fields. You can also use the solution mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154658/spring-boot-request-body-validation-on-same-dto-used-for-different-api.

Comment: @HarshKanakhara As I mentioned above, "Grouping constraints are not an option in my use case.".

Answer (score 0):

```
class ValidatorTest {

    private ValidatorA validatorA = new ValidatorA();
    private ValidatorB validatorB = new ValidatorB();

    @Test
    void validatorA_Test() {
        assertTrue(isValid(beanObject, validatorA));
    }

    @Test
    void validatorB_Test() {
        assertTrue(isValid(beanObject, validatorB));
    }

    private boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidator validator) {
        return validator.isValid(value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: With your test code, we would validate only the return value of the Validator#isValid method (and that's partly ok).   

But...   

As [Validator#validate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#validate-T-java.lang.Class...-) returns with constraint violations, I want to assert on it. And it's possible. However, since it's using also ValidatorB it contains additional violations as well.

Comment: It will be better if you can share your POJO and test cases with the actual result and expected result clearly. Also please refer to link  https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/#validating-programmatically:~:text=to%20none.-,A%20Custom%20Validator%20with%20Spring%20Boot,-If%20the%20available